# Why does these operations return 0.0?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

My question is why does,

```
import math
a = math.sqrt(3)
area = a * (1 / 2)
print area
```

give an output of 0.0, but,

```
import math
a = math.sqrt(3)
area = a / 2
print area
```

give an output of 0.866025403784

Comment: sorry about the formatting, it said if I indent 8 spaces it formats as code??

Comment: so the difference in the two examples is a/2 as oppossed to a*(1/2), and I'm using sublime btw

Comment: Because 1/2 is 0 in Python. Integer division. In the second example one operand is float so float division is done

Comment: Andrew Li - you're right, when I multiplied by 0.5 it gave desired output, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a problem of integer truncation in 2.X.

X / Y 
**Classic and true division**. 
In Python 2.X, this operator performs *classic division*, truncating results for integers, and keeping remainders (i.e., fractional parts) for floating-point numbers.
In 2.X, the / does classic division, performing truncating integer division if both operands are integers and float division (keeping remainders) otherwise.

In Python 3.X, it performs *true division*, always keeping remainders in floating-point results, regardless of types.
In 3.X, the / now always performs true division, returning a float result that includes any remainder, regardless of operand types.

In Python 2.X You can "fix" this by adding **from __future__ import division**        to your script. This will always perform a float division when using the / operator and use // for integer division.

*But you can **make at least one of the operands** in the division is a float, you'll get a float result.*

```
>>> from __future__ import division
```

> > > area=a*(1/2)
> > >       area
> > >       0.8660254037844386

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are using python 2.7 this is the problem with python 2.7 it evaluate 1/2 as zero because it think 1&&2 both as integer so it gives result as integer but in second case your math.sqrt() function return an double value so it gives result as double . but if you use python 3.0 the problem is fixed you get same result in both the cases you can try it it gives 1/2 as 0.5 .

Comment: thanks for your help guys :)